# Move all second td to before first td

Tags: jquery

Below is a table I have. I want to move all of the second `td`s to be before the first `td`s. My code mostly works but it only moves the contents inside the `td`s and not the `td` itself (contents and styling).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mrQuestionTable tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').before($(this).find('td:eq(0)').next().html());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="" class="mrQuestionTable" style="display: inline-block;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="mrQuestionText" style="color: #00659d;"><b><u>Chronic Inflammatory Demyelinating Polyneuropathy (CIDP)</u></b> patients personally managed in the past year</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div></div>
      <span style="">
   <div></div>
   <input type="text" name="_QA2_Qa_QA2__Scale" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0" class="mrEdit" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;" maxlength="2" value=""/>
   </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="mrQuestionText" style="color: red;"><b><u>Guillain-Barre Syndrome (GBS)</u></b>  patients personally managed  in the past year</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div></div>
      <span style="">
   <div></div>
   <input type="text" name="_QA2_Qb_QA2__Scale" id="_Q0_Q1_Q0" class="mrEdit" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;" maxlength="2" value=""/>
   </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to `$(this).find('td:eq(0)').before($(this).find('td:eq(1)'));`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mrQuestionTable tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').before($(this).find('td:eq(1)'));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table summary="" class="mrQuestionTable" style="display: inline-block;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="mrQuestionText" style="color: #00659d;"><b><u>Chronic Inflammatory Demyelinating Polyneuropathy (CIDP)</u></b> patients personally managed in the past year</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div></div>
      <span style="">
   <div></div>
   <input type="text" name="_QA2_Qa_QA2__Scale" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0" class="mrEdit" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;" maxlength="2" value=""/>
   </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="mrQuestionText" style="color: red;"><b><u>Guillain-Barre Syndrome (GBS)</u></b>  patients personally managed  in the past year</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div></div>
      <span style="">
   <div></div>
   <input type="text" name="_QA2_Qb_QA2__Scale" id="_Q0_Q1_Q0" class="mrEdit" autocomplete="off" style="width: 3em;" maxlength="2" value=""/>
   </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove html() from that method and have something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.mrQuestionTable tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('td:eq(0)').before($(this).find('td:eq(0)').next()); 
   });
});
```